# How do I access Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, and this probably seems like a stupid question, but just how do I actually boot up Ubuntu? First, I shrunk my hard drive and created a new partition, and then I've installed it (on a Toshiba laptop running Windows 8.1), and after restarting after setting it up from a USB, it just went straight into Windows. To boot from my USB, I press F12, but the only options in there are to boot from the HDD, USB, ODD and LAN. Does anyone know how I can go into Ubuntu rather than Windows?

Just to summarise what I've done, I disabled Secure Boot, Fast Boot and run Boot Repair, details [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11707969/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24799/discussion-on-question-by-jordi-brown-how-do-i-access-ubuntu).

Comment: @Mitch please read the comments carefully before deciding something is a conversation or not. I will re-post my comment here because it is a comment, *not* casual chat.

Comment: I noticed that you don't have a standard EFI partition. My suggestion to you at this point is to delete the two partitions you have created for Ubuntu, boot from the USB stick, and do another fresh install, following this guide: tecmint.com/ubuntu-15-04-installation-on-uefi-firmware (except 1-you aren't going to create a partition table and 2-you don't need a separate partition for your /home - unless you want to encrypt your home folder) At the end you should have three partitions: swap, EFI, and root.

Comment: @darksky when there is too many comments, its best to take it over to chat to continue.  That does not say in any way that its casual chat, but a way to get a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the UEFI loaded Windows after the secend boot after a fresh install. I ended up *replacing* the Windows boot files:

- open up the file manager from your live USB and navigate to the EFI boot partition
- rename the original `bootmgfw.efi` in the Microsoft folder to `bootmgfworig.efi` or something like that
- copy/paste the `grubx64.efi` from the Ubuntu folder to the Microsoft folder and rename it to `bootmgfw.efi`
- reboot

Hopefully the Grub bootloader shows up and you can boot Ubuntu. However you may no longer be able to boot Windows via the existing menu entry. If that is the case you have to add a custom menu entry to Grub:

- run `gksu gedit /etc/grub.d/40-custom` and add these lines:

> ```
> menuentry "Windows Bootloader" { 
> set root '(hd0,gpt2)'  
> chainloader (${root}/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfworig.efi) 
> }
> ```

- run `sudo update-grub`
- reboot